# PyTorch - How to use k-fold cross validation when the data is loaded through ImageFolder?

Tags: python, computer-vision, pytorch, conv-neural-network, torchvision

My data, which is images, is stored on the filesystem, and it is fed into my convolutional neural network through the `ImageFolder` data loader of `PyTorch`. Therefore, the `training`, `validation`, and `test` data is manually splitted into different folders on the filesystem. So, how can I apply `k-fold cross validation` when using `ImageFolder`?

Answer (score 1):

You can merge the fixed train/val/test folds you currently have using [`data.ConcatDataset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.ConcatDataset) into a single Dataset. Then you can use [`data.Subset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Subset) to randomly split the single dataset into different folds over and over.

Comment: I used `random_split` function which is defined in the same script with the `Subset` class. Does `Subset` constructor split the dataset randomly as well?

Comment: Also, are you sure that this way guarantees the existence of images for each class during training, validation, and test? For example, I have 7 target classes and images were organized according to their labels on the filesystem (as `ImageFolder` does work in this way).